# If $A$ is a nonmeasurable subset of $X$, and $E$ is measurable, s.t. $A\subseteq E$, then $\mu(E\setminus A)>0$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

> Let $\mu$ be an outer measure on a set $X$, If $A$ is a nonmeasurable subset of $X$, and $E$ is measurable, s.t. $A\subseteq E$, then $\mu(E\setminus A)>0$.

Now i don't ask, how to prove it. We proved it in class by contradiction. My Question is: Must it not be also nonmeasurable ? I mean from the nonmeasurability of $A$ follows that;

$\exists B$, s.t. $\mu(B)≠\mu(B\cap A)+\mu(B\cap A^c)$

we can take $X$ instead of $E$. If $X\setminus A$ is measurable, then

$\mu(B)=\mu(B\cap(X\setminus A))+\mu(B\cap(X\setminus A)^c)$

but

$\mu(B\cap(X\setminus A))+\mu(B\cap(X\setminus A)^c)=\mu(B\cap(X\cap A^c))+\mu(B\cap(X^c\cup A))=\mu(B\cap A)+\mu(B\cap A^c)$

Comment: Maybe they mean the outer measure of $E\backslash A$?

Comment: @TooOldForMath So can not take X instead of E?

Comment: No I just meant maybe the claim is $\mu_*(E\backslash A)>0$, then you don't even have to bother about measurability of $E\backslash A$.